# Exception in template helper: Error: Match error

Tags: meteor, minimongo

I'm trying to perform a custom sort using a comparator function from within a template helper in Meteor.

Here is my template helper:

```
Template.move_list.helpers({
  assets() {
    return Assets.find({}, { sort: sortFunction });
  }
});
```

And here is the comparator function:

```
const sortFunction = function (doc1, doc2) {
  const barcodes = Session.get('barcodesArray');

  if (barcodes.indexOf(doc1.barcode) === -1 || barcodes.indexOf(doc2.barcode) === -1) {
    return 0;
  }

  let last = null;
  _.each(barcodes, function (barcode) {
    if (barcode === doc1.barcode) last = doc1.barcode;
    if (barcode === doc2.barcode) last = doc2.barcode;
  });

  return last === doc1.barcode ? 1 : -1;
}
```

**Error**

When the page loads, the following error is returned:

`Exception in template helper: Error: Match error: Failed Match.OneOf, Match.Maybe or Match.Optional validation`

I put a breakpoint in chrome into the `sortFunction`, however the function was never entered and the breakpoint never reached.

Of course, the error is not throw when I remove `sort`.

**References**

This feature is not very well documented, however here is the [relevant part of the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#sortspecifiers):

> For local collections you can pass a comparator function which receives two document objects, and returns -1 if the first document comes first in order, 1 if the second document comes first, or 0 if neither document comes before the other. This is a Minimongo extension to MongoDB.

And the [commit by mitar](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/6008/commits/e6e1a2073d3861c445c77845055ce3ec75e9b9fd) adding the functionality, with example code from the test:

> ```
> var sortFunction = function (doc1, doc2) {
>   return doc2.a - doc1.a;
> };
> ```
>
> `c.find({}, {sort: sortFunction})`

Can anyone make sense of this error?

Comment: The issue should now be fixed.

Comment: Did you have the chance to try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

This issue should be resolved in Meteor >= v1.3.3.1.

Local collections (i.e, client-side and in-memory server-side collections) will allow to pass a function as the `sort` clause.

---

The error comes from the `mongo` package, where the spec does not allow `sort` to be a function.

@mitar changed `LocalCollection` in the `minimongo` package. `LocalCollection` is part of the `Mongo.Collection` object on the client (its `_collection` attribute), but queries are still checked according to the original `mongo` spec. **I believe this to be a bug**, as the spec was not updated to reflect the change.

To overcome this (in the meantime), either have the function accept a sub-field, such that the `sort` value is an object:

```js
var sortFunction = function (x, y) {
  return x - y;
};
c.find({}, {sort: {a: sortFunction}});
```

or use the `c._collection.find()` instead, which will work (as far as I can tell), except it will not apply any transformations defined for the collection.

```js
var sortFunction = function (doc1, doc2) {
  return doc2.a - doc1.a;
};
c._collection.find({}, {sort: sortFunction});
```